# Есть ли в GWT слайдер или как его сделать самому?

Tags: gwt, java

Искал, но не нашел никакой компоненты типа JSlider, только в GWT. Есть ли он, и если нет, то как можно написать такой слайдер самому?

Comment: @Dan: отметьте ответ как верный, чтобы вопрос закрылся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартного компонента нет, однако, на инкубаторе есть готовый.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/SliderBar

Кроме того, в extjs также есть такой компонент. Вот пример:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/VerticalHorizontalSliderExtGWT.htm

По extjs есть ещё демо-страничка, показываяющая разные контролы, что у них есть. Возможно, вас заинтересует:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что во 2ом и 3ем случае придется тащить целую библиотеку ради всего-навсего одного слайдера?

Comment: Да, верно. Только в первом библиотека - и есть слайдер. Во втором случае придётся тянуть целую библиотеку с кучей всего.

Comment: Первый вариант более-менее подходит. А как на ваш взгляд: стоит ли написать полностью свой собственный слайдер, чтобы ни от чего не зависеть? Но большие библиотеки точно ни к чему, они такие медленные!

Comment: Всё зависит от ваших потребностей и возможностей. Если у вас полно времени и настрой боевой, то можете для повышения своей квалификации и опыта написать свой. Если времени мало, то используйте готовый. Кроме того, всегда существует вероятность, что свой может в чём-то уступать тому готовому. Следует помнить, что чужой компонент поддерживают и тестируют другие люди, а свой компонент поддерживаете и теструете (я на это надеюсь) вы и только вы.